# Understanding the logic of nested for-loops

Tags: c

I wrote a program where the user inputs numbers n times; the program prints out the the numbers removing all duplicates.

On the code you will see that I initialized `seen = 0` at the beginning of the code and when I do so without initializing again on my for loop It won't print out the numbers correctly but when I do it will. Can somebody explain why? I would really like to understand this. 
I clarified my question on the code itself. Have a look:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int i, j, num, seen = 0; // here is where I first initialized it
                             // but I see that this is not necessary

    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        printf("Arr[%d] ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
         //seen = 0; If I initialize it here
         //          it will print out the numbers correctly
        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
       {
           if (arr[i]==arr[j])
           {
               seen = 1;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (!seen)
           printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: its not really clear what you are trying to do. The question suggests that you just want to print out the numbers entered, but the code has a nested loop with tests in it. SO what are you actually trying to do

Comment: Confused if you don't initialise seen it doesn't work, therefore initialising it is necessary. It's necessary, because seen is an int and only false when it equals zero....

Comment: i'll edit to be more clear

Comment: did you try using a debugger

Comment: I edited the question title because I am becoming rather annoyed with the endless series of questions that are so easily solved by basic techniques.

Comment: @Zan: The OP didn't ask how to use a debugger. That may or may not be the best solution to the OP's problem (and you've posted an answer saying so), but I don't think it's appropriate to change the question *assuming* that a particular solution is best. (There are certainly other approaches than using a debugger.)

Comment: I am new to C i'm sorry if i don't understand the code i just want to learn

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sure. He could add printf trace statements to find the problem. He could do a lot of things. Asking here seems like ... I just don't have words. Someone needs to show the new learners these basic self-teaching techniques.

Comment: @user2985083: I understand and I approve of learning. I just would like to help people learn how to learn more on their own. Watching your program run in a debugger is VERY educational.

Comment: @Zan is right about debuggers being educational and quite useful.  Now is the time when you're first starting out to get the hang of them.  I wish I had started learning to use them when I was just starting out...

Comment: thanks guys i'm trying to download it for mac

Comment: "its not really clear what you are trying to do" -- It's clear to me without reading the accompanying text ... it's printing non-duplicate entries.

Comment: @ZanLynx That's an awful edit that violates SO basics ... please don't do that sort of thing. And this has nothing to do with debugging, it's about understanding programming logic.

Comment: @JimBalter: Please feel free to create a question title for this which is meaningful and helpful in answering the question. Really, that is what I started to do before .... well. I guess I just lost my cool a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't reset `seen=0` in the outer loop, the program thinks that it has seen every one after the first one that it finds.

Googling `gdb tutorial` yielded [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf) that looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the value of your `seen` variable *means*.

You iterate over the array of numbers. For each number, you do the following:

- Loop over the *previous* numbers in the array, and check whether the current number has already been seen.
- Print the current number only if it *hasn't* already been seen.

`seen` should be true only if you've already seen the *current* number. The way your program is currently written, it remains true as long as the program continues to run, though the old value becomes irrelevant as soon as the outer loop advances to a new number.

In fact, it would be even better to move the declaration of `seen` (along with its initialization to `0` inside the outer loop. Since its value is not meaningful outside one iteration of the outer loop, it might as well only exist within each iteration of the outer loop.

(Running your program under a source level debugger such as `gdb` is one way to find errors like this, but not the only one. Re-reading your code and reasoning about what it does vs. what it should do is another useful approach. Adding `printf` calls to show the values of variables as the program runs is another.)

Answer (score 0):

Please learn about **debugger** programs.

In an IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse it is built in.

Using GCC on Linux command line it is called `gdb`. You compile your program with the `-g` flag to make GCC include debug information. Then you run `gdb program-name` and `start` and `n`, then hit return as it steps through the program. There are also many other commands.

With that you should be able to solve this problem and many others.